# Instr, vbtextcompare in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
sub find_cust_comp(searchrange as range, searchvalue as string)
'this sub is called from shinvoice and fmgetcustomer
dim cell as range
dim c as byte
'searchable is either customer or company range
for each cell in searchrange
    c = instr(1,cell.value, searchvalue, vbtextcompare)
    if c> 0 then
    'add matching items to listbox
    'add the customer name
    fmgetcustomer.lbcustomer.additem shmaster.range("A" & cell.row).value
    'add the company name
    fmgetcustomer.lbcustomer.list(fmgetcustomer.lbcustomer.listcount-1,1) _
    = shmaster.range("B" &cell.row).value
    next if
next cell
end sub
```

---

shmaster is a excel worksheet. fmgetcustomer is a userform. lbcustomer is a listbox.

---

1. I'm not sure what's the INSTR function really do? Yes,I already checked with office documentation.
2. *range("A" & cell.row)* I also confused. I have no idea where it refer to.
3. Tutorial [link](https://www.udemy.com/course/excel-vba-and-macros-course/learn/lecture/10053934#overview)

Answer (score 0):

Function **Instr** return index of searched word or letter in text;

```
 if c> 0 then
```

that means if text is found

```
shmaster.range("A" & cell.row).value
```

It reffers to first cell within range where specifed text is found

```
next if
```

go to next cell and do the same till all cells will be checked